# Not able to test ag-grid floating filter

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

Following this article to enable column filter in ag-grid

https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/floating-filters/

**Current behavior**
Displayed row count still shows the initialised row count

**Expected behavior**
Grid should filter and display row based on filter criteria
gridApi?.getDisplayedRowCount() still shows the intial row count

```
expect(gridApi?.getDisplayedRowCount()).toBe(1);
```

**Complete Unit test**

```
fit('should filter by greater than value entered in input box', fakeAsync(() => {

fixture.autoDetectChanges()
flush();


const gridApi = component?.gridOptions?.api;
console.log('row count --->',gridApi?.getDisplayedRowCount());

 const inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.ag-floating-filter-input'));

const newEve = new Event('input');
console.log(inputElement)

inputElement.nativeElement.value = 'hello';
inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

flush();
expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.ag-floating-filter-input')).nativeElement.value).toBe('hello');
expect(gridApi?.getDisplayedRowCount()).toBe(1);


}));
```